# Advice on how i should structure my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've progressed well on my dashboard i'm creating for a plumbing business (My Own) we specialise solely in new homes, and i'm trying to automate a lot of the processes i currently have to do manually, mostly arbitrary paperwork and management of jobs. I can also give links to the builder so he can track the progress of the property and the history.

The general gist of this is so i can create a new property, From there the house plan is added for the property where then all sorts of details, like length of drains, type of roof, distances between areas can be added to children tables. This info will be used to create a quote from also.

I would like some advice on how i should structure all of this. I am using php and mysql.

I get a monthly database of prices emailed to me from my supplier in CSV format, so i would want to update that table in my database monthly also. So that each new address can use that pricing to create the quote, once the quote is generated i can save that out to another table so the prices remain frozen for that period when the pricing was set.

One main question i have in terms of doing the quotes is how would i link my data to the pricing table? As i can not guarantee that the list i get will always be in the exact same order, also if new products are added it would mess up any sort of id system i had in place.

I was thinking maybe the only way was to have each item search the database for the exact product code, which seems the most logical.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZQ1N.png

I've attached an image trying to figure out how i should structure it in my head. This would also include a pricing list obviously and many other tables that would be children of the house plan.

The property Table is going to be the main table, which will have a owner tied to the property. As this can change if sold etc. Then a property has a house plan added to it, as some properties can have multiple homes on it.

The house plan table then also has certain stages attached to that plan, "internal drainage", "External drainage" etc which will all be able shown on the page as cards underneath the parent house plan.

Anyways i may have confused you guys but any advice is greatly appreciated or even some directions to some good advice. I have searched but my search terms leave a lot to be desired so i'm not too sure exactly were to look.

Thanks guys

Comment: From your point of view, each property can have only one owner, so `owner` is an `attribute` of `property` (so `owner` is a column in the `property` table). If that's not the case then you would have three tables to represent this relationship: `properties`,`owners`,`property_owner`. You definitely would not have a column called `mr` or `mrs` in any of that! Those are values, not attributes.

Comment: Also, as internal and external drainage appear to contain the exact same columns, these would be one table, with an extra column identifying which drainage we're talking about. Presumably `id` in this context refers to `property_id`?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have read up on normalization of data tables. Getting a firm grasp of normal forms will go a long way to helping you lay out your database. I do suggest that you tackle to most useful and important information first and get a system going or you will tend to lose impetus as this will be a big undertaking.

The first recommendation is that your ID columns be renamed appropriately or you will have headaches later when your working on it late at night trying to figure out your foreign key relationship are not working. It is also better to have your ID columns be relevant rather then arbitrary. That being said some will argue that there is more overhead with using relevant rather then arbitrary keys. I feel that the gain outweighs slight lost.

Just remember don't feel you need to get all fields into the database from the start. If you need to create a table that has just a primary key and a name in it just so you have the ID then do it. You can add extra fields later. Tackle what you are having to deal with today worry about the extras later.

To answer the question about quotes. Your going to create a table for Suppliers, Products SupplierProducts(This is where you will map your products to you suppliers). Your going to have to figure out if their product codes are the same or not. This is where having upc codes on your CSV database would be nice, would be is the key word here. Italics are your Primary Keys.

- You have your Suppliers Table: *SupplierID*, Name, Address etc.
- You have your Products Table: *ProductID*, Description, Price(that you sell at), and any other relevant information that you need for your products and services.
- You have your SuppliersProduct Table: *SupplierID*, *ProductID*, (SupplierSKU, UPC, or what ever number that supplier uses to identify that product). CurrentPrice, SupplierDescription, and any other relevant data that comes in your csv files.
- You have your Quotes Table: *QuoteID*, date, ClientID etc.
- You have your QuotesDetails Table: *QuoteID*, *QuoteDetailID*(You could leave this out too and PK with ProductID), ProductID, Quoted Price(You need to store this as prices change you don't want this to change), Qty, TotalPrice, etc...

You don't need to map out all of your ProductID to SupplierSKU right from the start you can set the PK as SupplierID, SupplierSKU, and have SupplierID and ProductID as an additional index. If they all used UPC codes you would be home free and you can just use that as your ProductID or you could do that anyway. You will however need to have an import code to bring the CSV file into your database. If you want you can have each as a separate table as well but this would add more complexity to the system.

Your quotes will use your ProductID. If you use your own ProductIDs it will be easiest to have a mapping routine while your doing your orders. If you want to get fancy you can generate orders from your quotes or make it a separate system. Only you can decide on how much time you want to spend writing the front end to this and how much of a difference it will make.

Make your software matches your business rules and flow not the other way around. So however you are doing it now make the software do it that way. A database should have all the rules in it to keep your data correct for you business rules. This is where triggers and stored procedures come into play. Make sure you investigate this issue before going further as migrating to another DB because of MySQL/InnoDB short commings is not fun.

One other note is if you have your tables done correctly order is not important. Here is where understanding database normalization come into play as the one of the normal forms say that order of records and columns are irrelevant. It must have a unique ID and an ID can be multiple fields.

Comment: Thanks! Great advice, sometimes just need to hear it from more experienced people

Comment: +1 for all that typing

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw yourself an [Entity-relationship model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model). Write out all of the different "parts" of your proposed database all as separate entities, and then think of how they're all related to each other.

No one here will be able to give you advice on the ideal database structure because we don't have nearly enough context from you. You have to think of all the possible scenarios that exist and how everything will tie together. The diagram will help you do that. Once you've made a visual model, you can build the schema.

Comment: Thanks! Am going to look further into this!